# write program to perform sum = 1+ (1+2) + (1+2+3) + ... + (1+2...+n)

Tags: c

I can't get the codes right.
Can somebody help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int n, sum,i,j;

 printf("Please enter an integer, n = ");
 scanf("%d", &n);

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
         sum = sum + n;
 printf("sum = %d", sum);


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add some curly brackets. Code is singular.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?  It's C code.

Comment: @Steven:  FWIW, it's also legal C++ code.  Not that I'd teach a C++ beginner about `scanf()`.

Comment: Also, the indenting of printf is not the correct(although it's valid C code).

Comment: Added more spaces to indenting; corrected indentation of `printf`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You are not initialising `sum`. Initialise it with `0`.
2. You shouldn't be adding `n` at each step, but `j`.

Of course, this is to fix your current code. There are better approaches to solving the problem, which others have already mentioned.

**Edit**:

Just for fun, here's a formula that allows you to solve the problem in `O(1)`:

Your sum is equal to `n*(n + 1)*(2*n + 1) / 12 + n*(n + 1) / 4`.

This is obtained by writing it as a sum and using the fact that the sum of the first `n` consecutive squares is `n(n + 1)(2n + 1) / 6` and the sum of the first `n` positive ints is `n(n + 1)/2`. +1 if you can find a nicer form of the formula.

Comment: thanks alot. previously, i kept changing j and n but still couldn't get the solution. now i get that the problem was the initialization.

Comment: here it is, my codes.
gee, there are so many math formulas.
thanks anyway.
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int n, sum=0,i,j;
 
 printf("Please enter an integer, n = ");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
  sum = sum + j;
  printf("sum = %d", sum);
  

 return 0;
}

Comment: @user391967 - just so you know you do not need 2 for loops to accomplish this.

Comment: Mathematically the formula is sound; integer division will yield incorrect results though.

Comment: @Austin Salonen - in its current form yes, but you can continue the calculations and get a nicer form which won't have the same problem. Others have already posted two such forms.

Answer (score 9):

No need for recursion, just look at the math:

```
1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + ... + (1+2+3+...+n)
```

is equal to

```
1*n + 2*(n-1) + 3*(n-2) + ... + n
```

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing - I'm not a native speaker, but I just felt that somethings was wrong here...thanks for setting me straights.

Comment: @GMan : A coworker just said it was British, interesting.  Withdrawn :)

Comment: @Stephen: I just read The Canterville Ghost again today, and nobody could have said it like Oscar Wilde: "...an excellent example of the fact that [the British] have really everything in common with America nowadays, except, of course, language."

Comment: If you go down that road you could as well just print out `n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6`

Answer (score 5):

Not what you expected, but this **is** the best solution ;)

```
int calculate (int n) {
  return (2*n + 3*n*n + n*n*n) / 6;
}
```

Comment: I see now that you gave a similar answer. I used the same formulas for sum of ints and sum of squares. You just didn't finish the calculation.
BTW, sth gave an even nicer result in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Think this through.  You have one sum you're accumulating, and you have a series of values.  Each value can be generated from the previous one by adding the index.  So why do you have nested loops?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it iteratively, like you tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, t, n, sum;
    printf("Please enter an integer, n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    t = sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        t += i;
        sum += t;
    }
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

But there's a closed-form formula as IVlad suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `sum`, so you're adding everything to a random garbage value.  Stick `sum = 0;` before your loops

Answer (score 0):

Start with the math, see if you can find some pattern.

```
if n = 0 , res = 0?
if n = 1 , res = 1
if n = 2 , res = 1 + (1+2) 
if n = 3 , res = 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3)
```

for each n, res is ??

Comment: I've seem some teachers mark down for calculating sum based on a derived shortcut/known answer.

Comment: Telling him to guess it isn't helpful. There are algorithms for arriving at a formula.

Comment: @IVlad: There are, but I'm pretty sure the point here is for him to learn how to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main(void)
 {
   int total=1;
   int sumtotal = 0;
   int n=5;

   for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
     {
       total+=i;
       sumtotal+=total;
     }
   //sumtotal should give you 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int main(void)
{
    int     n, sum;

    printf("\nPlease enter a postive integer value");    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    sum = n * ( n + 1 )/ 2;
    printf("\n%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

n * (n -(n - 1))

```
int n, sum 

for n = 0; n <= 3; n ++ {
    sum += n * (n -(n - 1))
 }
```

works for factorials too (change operator and set sum to 1):

```
int n, sum 

sum = 1

for n = 0; n <= 3: n++{
    sum *= n * (n -(n -1))
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid C.  Also, `(n - (n - 1))` is just 1, so you're really just doing `sum += n` on each iteration.

Comment: *facepalm* thanks for pointing that out, don't know why I didn't realize that before